# How to rectify a JFrog Pipelines sync issue caused due to failed validate approver?

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

Added a pipeline source with approval step which had an approvers list

```yaml
pipelines:
  - name: testing
    steps:
      - name: test_step
        type: Bash
        configuration:
          requiresApproval:
            approvers:
              - nehamishra
            notifications:
              - integrationName: test_slack
          execution:
            onExecute:
              - echo "Got the approval"
```

The pipeline sync failed with below error message

> undefined: failed to validate approver nehamishra when validating configuration.requiresApproval.approvers list for Bash step test_step with error: Artifactory user does not exist.

Comment: Multi-line code quotations should be started and ended with a row of three backticks on an otherwise-empty line.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution to fix the above error is to have only relevant artifactory users who are active in the list of approvers in the [approval gate step](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Approval+Gates).